# Automatic scrolling with angularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a list of items, inside a div, with a ng-repeat angular directive. And I need this list, to use an automatic scrolling, it's a [DEMO](http://nishadmenezes.github.io/super-treadmill.js/) (it's, use the jquery super-treadmill). How can I do this with angular js (version 1.6)?

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div ng-repeat="model in collection">
        <h1>{{model.name}}</h1>
        <p>{{model.description}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share what have you tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with simple directive

```
app.directive('startTreadmill', function(){
     return {
         link: function(scope, element, attr){
              $(element).startTreadmill({ direction: "down"});
         }
     }
})


<div class="panel-body" start-treadmill>
    <div ng-repeat="model in collection">
        <h1>{{model.name}}</h1>
        <p>{{model.description}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```